# Electron concentration in an intrinsic semiconductor at room temperature

Tags: semiconductors, physics, solid-state-devices

For a Si atom, band gap energy is around 1.1 eV which means that an electron in valence band needs at least this much energy to jump to conduction band.
Also, at room temperature, typically energy of about 25 meV is 'readily' available. This implies that at room temperature no electron should make the transition from valence to conduction band. Still experimentally it is found that electron concentration of about 1.5*10^10/cc is present in conduction band of Si at room temperature.
How is this possible?

Comment: Go calculate the number of atoms of Si per cc, then get back to us.

Comment: Even if number of Si per cc is large, there shouldn't be any electron in the conduction band of those Si atoms. So even in that regard number of electrons in conduction band should be zero.
Is it not so?

Answer (score 1):

Thermal voltage (\$\sim 25\,meV\$) is the average kinetic energy of particles in gas. It's not the total energy of each and every electron.

The actual energy distribution among the electrons is described by Fermi energy and temperature via [Fermi Dirac distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics). At zero temperature, all electrons have energy less than Fermi energy. At non-zero temperature, some electrons have energy greater than Fermi energy.

So at any any temperature, the probability that an energy level is occupied is given by Fermi Dirac distribution, \$f(E)\$. The density of available states in an energy interval \$dE\$ at any energy is \$D(E)dE\$. Where \$D(E)\$ is the electron density of states function. Then the total electron concentration can be calculated by,

$$n=\int\limits_{E_C}^{\infty}f(E)D(E)dE$$

\$E_C\$ is the bottom of conduction band and \$D(E)\propto\sqrt{E}\$. Few approximations are used to do this integration. After integration,
$$n=\sqrt{N_CN_V}\exp\left(-\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}\right)$$

where \$N_C\$ and \$N_V\$ are material and temperature dependent parameters called as the effective density of states and \$E_g\$ is the bandgap of the material.

For silicon at room temperature, the bandgap is \$E_g=1.1\,eV\$ and the effective density of states values are in the order of \$10^{19}\,cm^{-3}\$. This will result in an intrinsic carrier concentration \$n_i\sim 10^{10}\$. The exact values can be obtained from books.

Answer (score 0):

At room temperature, you got average thermal energy of "all" electrons = KT = 0.025eV.
But energy of electrons always follow some non uniform distribution. Which implies that you may get some electrons containing higher and lower energies than that of average. And electrons nearer to valance band maxima will have sufficient energy to jump over the band gap.

Answer (score 0):

The density of Si = 2.33 g/cm³

The molar mass of Si = 28.0855 g/mol

So 1 cm³ of Si will contain 4 * 2.33/28.0855 * 6.022 * 10^23 electrons in the outer valence band which is approximately 2*10^23.

So if as stated 1.5*10^10 are present in the conduction band then approximately 1 in 10^13 of the electrons have achieved sufficient energy to be there i.e. a very tiny proportion. This is consistent with the commentary that 25meV is the average of a very broad distribution of energy in the system.